# Disk Utility fails to erase new SSDs on iMac 2012, but succeeds on MacBook 2009 (both 13.5.2)

Tags: macos, disk-utility, imac, ssd, external-disk

The initialisation of my two new SSDs failed.

I tried this on two systems, both with OCLP, macOS 13.5.2

- MacBook late 2009 6,2
- iMac 27" 2012 iMac 13,2, Time Machine switched off.

On the Macbook there is no problem.
On the iMac, 'Restoring "Container disk3" from "MacIntosh HD"' it fails after a minute or so with:

```
Erasing “JMicron Tech Media” (disk2) and creating “Untitled”

Unmounting disk
Creating the partition map
Waiting for partitions to activate
Formatting disk2s2 as Mac OS Extended (Journaled) with name Untitled
newfs_hfs: WriteBuffer:  pwrite(3, 0x7f96bb221000, 1048576, 0): Resource busy
newfs_hfs: write (sector 0): Resource busy

Mounting disk
Could not mount disk2s2 after erase
File system formatter failed. : (-69832)

Operation failed…
```

Suggestions on how to debug this are also appreciated!

Comment: You say "two new SSDs failed". They both failed in the iMac, but they erased in the MBP? So, having erased them with the MBP, have you then installed one in the iMac? (Avoiding damage to the heat sensor?) What happens now? Have you tried installing macOS from an installer media onto the SSD?

Comment: I am considering installing the SSD in the iMac, perform a clean install (with OCLP) from a USB drive and the use Migration.
Still, the iMac should be able to format the SSD with apfs and Mac OS extended.
Note that formatting with FAT32 works fine.
To install the disk I will have to cut open the iMac. I have not yet come to do that.

Comment: If you have not yet installed the disks in the iMac, how are they connected? Any chance you've got a dodgy cable?

Comment: I have a new 9€ SATA600 to USB3 cable that I use for both the MacBook and the iMac.

Comment: After dozens failures it suddenly formatted to an apple format! I proceeded to the replication and hat also is running. So far so good. I changed nothing. Not the cable not the software. I did insert a 5€ USB hub but that shouldn't matter. Possibly the FAT32 formatting helped update some outdated prefs?

Comment: Correction: insertion of the 5€ USB3 hub changes a lot, reproducibly. SSD formatting works with it and fails without it.
Reciprocating the iMac HDD now fails after one or two hours, no immediately as before, with error 49157.

Comment: With CCC I was able to make a bootable 13.5.2 drive. If I find out what actually goes  wrong without the USB hub I will report it to Apple and here.
The bounty is still on for an answer that sheds some light on this.